# Letters are not properly underlined

Tags: html, css

I want to implement a text-resizer functionality. The text should resize depending the letter clicked. There is a small, medium and large letter, and if one clicked should be underlined, in order to inform the user the text size has chosen.

```css
#smalltext {
  font-size: 1em;
}

#mediumtext {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

#largetext {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.resizer {
  margin: 15px;
}

a.resizer:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.resizer-selected {
  text-decoration: underline;
  /*border-bottom: 2px solid black; */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="resizer resizer-selected" id="smalltext">
    <span>A</span>
  </a>
  <a class="resizer resizer-selected" id="mediumtext">
    <span>A</span>
  </a>
  <a class="resizer resizer-selected" id="largetext">
    <span>A</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

The problem is with css. As you can see in the snippet, only the third letter is properly underlined.
The line in first and second letter exceeds to the right. I tried `text-decoration: underline;` and `border-bottom` and is the same problem.
The size seems not to be a problem, as i tried the same size for all three, but the problem remained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;` on `.resizer` to bind the letter spacing to the font-size:

```css
#smalltext {
 font-size: 1em;
}
#mediumtext {
 font-size: 1.25em;
}
#largetext {
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

.resizer {
 margin: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.resizer:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.resizer-selected {
  text-decoration: underline;
 /*border-bottom: 2px solid black; */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="resizer resizer-selected" id="smalltext">
    <span>A</span>
  </a>
  <a class="resizer resizer-selected" id="mediumtext">
    <span>A</span>
  </a>
  <a class="resizer resizer-selected" id="largetext">
    <span>A</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.resizer-selected > span {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```